Remove Nautilus starred column and folder in Ubuntu 24.04
I want to remove the starred column in Nautilus, which takes up unnecessary space. I also want to hide the Starred bookmark (the top one in the sidebar). I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Is there a way to do that?

I think you need describe your problem better...

you might find this superUser post of some interest and also this closed question from GNOME Discourse

Thanks @graham. From what I read, this is basically a bug. There is no option to hide the star column at this moment. The original poster there (tekstryder) says he wrote a patch to fix that, but he does not seem to share it with us.

That about sums it up.

The patch is simple if you want to build it yourself: https://pastebin.com/GGF3LJSB

Thanks for your help @KhalidAbuShawarib. I am unsure how to proceed, as I never coded in C. Would you be so kind as to indicate the steps needed to implement the patch?
